# Delphi - open a zipfile read-only

Tags: delphi, zip

I use the internal TZipFile.
When I open the zip then Delphi seems to open it exclusively.
As long as the zipfile isn't freed the file access is denied

```
lZipFile := tZipFile.Create;
if lZipFile.IsValid( sPath) then begin
  lZipFile.Open( sPath, zmRead );
...
// access denied to sPath
end;
lZipFile.Free;
```

I only want to read. Why delphi is behaving that way?
If I want to access a zip-file several times then I have to make a local copy and work with that copy? I don't really like this workaround. First of all since the zipfile could be huge.

Any idea what I can do to access the same zip in a read-only mode at the same time more than once?

Comment: Try using LZipFile.Open(SPath, zmReadWrite) See this: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/System.Zip.TZipMode

Comment: Read/write isn't the correct mode. That will lock the file.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I realised that 10 minutes after posting my comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a `TFileStream` instance opened with the desired share mode. Then use the overloaded `Open` method of `TZipFile` that accepts a `TStream`.

Be aware that `TZipFile.IsValid` will try to open the file exclusive, too. As `IsValid` does nothing what `Open` also does, I added a *try-except* block to catch any invalid or unaccessible target. The call to `IsValid` can thus be omitted.

```
  zip := TZipFile.Create;
  try
    stream := TFileStream.Create(sPath, fmOpenRead + fmShareDenyWrite);
    try
      try
        zip.Open(stream, zmRead);
      except
        on EZipException do begin
          // access denied to sPath
        end;
      end;
    finally
      stream.Free;
    end;
  finally
    zip.Free;
  end;
```

Comment: You mean like in system.zip? I tried TFileStream.Create(ZipFileName, LMode, fmShareDenyWrite) - but the file stays locked (directly after creating the tfilestream.

Comment: Better this way: `TFileStream.Create(ZipFileName, fmOpenRead + fmShareDenyWrite)`. The share mode belongs to the file mode parameter, not the the Rights.

Comment: Use `or` rather than `+`

Comment: Thanks - this helped. Also the hint that the TZipFile.IsValid is opening the file exlusive too. Is there a reason why Delphi opens this exclusive?

Comment: @Jens Because the RTL developers are not as skilled and experienced as they should be

Comment: @UweRaabe If you use the overloaded `Open` method of `TZipFile` that accepts `TStream` as you suggested then you don't even need to call `TZipFile.IsValid` prior opening the file to check its integrity as that is already done in the overloaded `Open` method and would raise an exception if the file integrity check fails.

Comment: @SilverWarior, Yes, that is why I added the try-except block.

Comment: @UweRaabe Yes you did. But in your answer you are also mentioning that `TZipFile.IsValid` opens the file with exclusive access which could confuse the OP about whether he needs to call that method besides your code or not. Any way I think your answer should clearly state that with your code there is no need to call `TZipFile.IsValid` method at all as it is already done so internally in `TZipFile.Open` method..

Comment: The comment of Uwe was fine. I check sometimes only whether a file is a zip (just to add it to a list). And this I would have done with IsValid.